# Edit MenuBar with Css in JavaFx

Tags: java, css, javafx, menubar, scenebuilder

Thanks for reading. I have trying to edit a menu-bar with css but the menu item don't changed.

I realized the parts of menu-bar are:  Menubar, menu, menu-items but the last one don't work rightly. Help

```
.menu-bar{
  -fx-background-color: peru;
  -fx-border-color:  #f0cd90;
 -fx-border-width: 2

}

.menu-bar .label {
    -fx-font-size: 25 pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-text-fill: #dedede;

}


.menu:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #bc784e;
}

.menu-item .label{
     -fx-font-size: 25 pt;
    -fx-label-line-length: 8;
      -fx-background-color: #cc66ff;
}
```

I'm using Scene builder.

Comment: Hi Juan. Specifically, what changes do you want to perform on menu-items? Do you want to define their font size and background color?

Comment: I have the same problem , in scene builder I can't change the menu-items and I don't know why. bug maybe ?

Comment: yes, probably a bug or idk really i'm still searching.  Crferreira i'm trying to change hover and other performances. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make:

```
.menu .label{     -fx-text-fill: black;}
```

Reference: https://forums.oracle.com/message/10402062